# How to make background blurred when modal window is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal window using HTML, CSS and JavaScript 
I would like the body background to be blurred when a modal window is opened , so that the opened window looks focused
[ On a Side Note , My modal has functionality to open and close multiple modal windows one by one , so if second modal window is opened , i want the blurred effect to be applied on the first window too along with the body of course ]

Edit - i created a css class with blur effect

```
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

But i don't know JavaScript well enough to have it implemented ,also some people recommending it just needs css , that is the case when you create a bootstrap modal which mine is not ..The opening and closing of modal here is handled by JavaScript and not by a css class like in case of bootstrap modal

I am attaching  the Javascript and CSS codes below in snippets 
Can someone please adjust the codes to have the desired effect ?

if someone wants to have a look on the whole codes including HTML and output , you can check it [here](https://jsbin.com/pekaronuna/edit?output)

JavaScript

```
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
  }

  function checkRenableScroll() {
    if (!open_modals.length) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 3.125rem;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: -0.25rem;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: You could add blur with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388840/can-you-blur-the-content-beneath-behind-a-div

Comment: I can do the css part. I already created a css class defining the blur effect. But i don't know how to implement that in JavaScript. CSS alone can't do it. Because opening and closing of modals is handled by JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You can use [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur) filter to achieve that effect. Have a css class with blur filter and apply that class conditionally to your modals.

Comment: I saw some css blur tutorials. I can now do the blur effect on background of image ( the basic ones you can say ) . But doing it on a active modal is still something i am not able to do. If someone can edit the codes to have the desired effect , i do appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 1):

I added js:

```
if(index>0){
            spans[index-1].parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("open");
          }else{
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }
```

Update css:

```
.open > *{
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
.modal{
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);

}
.modal .open{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);

}
```

full js :

```
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

     if(this.parentElement.nodeName == 'BODY'){
       document.body.classList.add("open");
     } else{
       this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add("open");
     } 
    }
  }

  function checkRenableScroll() {
    if (!open_modals.length) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];

          if(index>0){
            spans[index-1].parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("open");
          }else{
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];
          if(index>0){
            spans[index-1].parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("open");
          }else{
            document.body.classList.remove("open");
          }
          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            checkRenableScroll();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Demo here: https://codepen.io/phong18/pen/VwZzZQm

Comment: Thanks you so much for helping.   The codes are working well on single modal demonstration. But when i added these codes in my website , once a modal window is opened , both the body background and modal window becomes blurred and always remains like that

Comment: You can check the issue here - https://jsbin.com/pihuvesuye/edit?output.   Only the html codes are different.    The css and JavaScript code is exactly same from your codepen .So something in html causing issue maybe

Comment: I found it. Its happening to due to <section id="xyz">. </section>.      Now it will be easy for you to to fix i guess

Comment: I have made it a new question so that you can find everything at a single place - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798103/body-background-blur-functionality-not-working-well-universally

Comment: I fixed, let try and let me know.